# How to integrate Create-react-app with passport middleware?

Tags: reactjs, passport.js

I have a requirement to authorize the user based on passport strategy.

react app created with CREATE-REACT-APP
passport js - passport-facebook strategy.
As far as I know, passport js can be work along with express only.

Since I have created app using CREATE-REACT-APP all configuration is auto generated and unable to integrate passport js in same.

Can anybody help me to fix this issue?

Comment: create-react-app is meant to be used for front-end application, however if you want to serv your build with any server, like node + express, you only need to create a file, somes import with npm and life goes on !

Comment: Hi Fabien, Thanks for your answering, In my understanding, In the production env, I can deploy the create-react-app into any server, such as node + express, so I can configure passport for it.  But how about development env, how to test the passport with create-react-app?

Comment: You can eject create react app if you want to customize the app as you want by running "npm run eject".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is my implementation of create-react-app & Passport.js in an express app. (https://github.com/Tetsuya3850/MERN-Sprint/tree/master/auth)

Comment: Thanks, It fixes my issue.

Comment: Oh great! if it all worked, please accept an answer! (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: This answer must have changed, because this repo makes no reference to "passport" anywhere